# Compilation error when compiling rstudio-server?

Tags: r, rstudio, rstudio-server

I am trying to compile rstudio-server in Mac OS X 10.11.4 but I am getting some compilation error related to libboost. Any pointers on how to troubleshoot this?

Note: I had previously installed boost with `brew install boost`.

(The build output below is abbreviated)

`sudo make install` gives this:

```
gwtc:
 [java] Compiling module org.rstudio.studio.RStudio
 [java]    Compiling 4 permutations
 [java]       Compiling permutation 0...
 [java]       Process output
 [java]          Compiling
 [java]             Compiling permutation 1...
 [java]          Compiling
 [java]             Compiling permutation 2...
 [java]       Compiling permutation 3...
 [java]    Compile of permutations succeeded
 [java]    Compilation succeeded -- 217.782s
 [java] Linking into Desktop/thingamabob/rstudio/src/gwt/www/rstudio; Writing extras to Desktop/thingamabob/rstudio/src/gwt/extras/rstudio
 [java]    Link succeeded
 [java]    Linking succeeded -- 4.739s

build:

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
Total time: 3 minutes 48 seconds
[ 19%] Built target gwt_build
[ 53%] Built target rstudio-core
[ 57%] Built target rstudio-core-hunspell
[ 58%] Built target rstudio-core-synctex
[ 59%] Built target rstudio-monitor
[ 59%] Built target rstudio-r
[ 59%] Built target rstudio-session-workers
[ 60%] Building CXX object src/cpp/session/CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionDependencies.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object src/cpp/session/CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionDiagnostics.cpp.o
[ 60%] Building CXX object src/cpp/session/CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionDirty.cpp.o
[ 61%] Building CXX object src/cpp/session/CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionErrors.cpp.o

etc...

[ 92%] Building CXX object src/cpp/session/CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/modules/SessionCrypto.cpp.o
[ 92%] Building CXX object src/cpp/session/CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/SessionModuleContext.mm.o
make[2]: *** No rule to make target `/opt/rstudio-tools/boost/boost_1_50_0/lib/libboost_date_time.a', needed by `src/cpp/session/rsession'.  Stop.
make[1]: *** [src/cpp/session/CMakeFiles/rsession.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

**Previous steps**

1. I cloned the github repo (https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio)
2. Created the build dir
3. Ran `cmake .. -DRSTUDIO_TARGET=Server -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=OSX`
4. Fixed those missing deps along the way by running the script `install-dependencies-osx` (in folder `rstudio/dependencies/osx`)
5. Now that the configuration was successful I simply ran `sudo make install` as described above.

Comment: What steps did you follow before `make install`? Did you install dependencies? And did you run `cmake` as mentioned in the INSTALL file?

Comment: Yes and yes. Please see my recent edit at the end of the post.

Comment: OK thanks. I have installed rstudio from the github repos in OSX 10.11.x and now in 10.12.x. I remember had some problems at the beginning but not sure it was libboost. Unfortunately can't check my computer until Tuesday. One thing, the error is looking for boost in `/opt/rstudio-tools/`. Is there where it should be? Where did brew install it? (Also have brew- just don't remember the details of installation...).

Comment: I found this link that might be relevant/useful (see last post mentioning /opt/rstudio-tools): https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200660747-Rstudio-and-packages-compiled-with-boost

Comment: Thanks! I will try to install boost with the rstudio installation script and remove brew's version.

Comment: Installing brew's version of boost did not help. The file `libboost_date_time.a` is still missing from the installation...

Comment: Check my response for installing from github. You should **not** use the brew version of boost for this. Incidentally, you can install rstudio server with `brew install rstudio-server` (if you are OK with the current release version).

Answer (score 1):

These are the steps I just followed to get RStudio server up and running in OSX.

## Install dependencies

- XCode (or command line tools)
- R from [here](http://r-project.org).
- JDK from [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk8-downloads-2133151.html).
- Install cmake, ant and openssl.

You can install them with brew:

```
brew install cmake

brew install ant

brew install openssl
```

- Clone rstudio github repository.

The project will be cloned into a directory called `rstudio`. This will be ROOT below.

```
git clone https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio.git
```

- Install RStudio dependencies

This will install, among other things, the *boost* library in /opt.

```
cd rstudio/dependencies/osx
./install-dependencies-osx
```

## Build RStudio server

- Create build directory

(Check the value of ROOT above).

```
cd ROOT
mkdir build
cd build
```

- Configure

(check INSTALL file in ROOT directory for options).

```
cmake .. -DRSTUDIO_TARGET=Server -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release
sudo make install
```

## Configure system:

- Copy launchd file to /Library/LaunchDaemon

This will be used to run the rstudio server service.

```
sudo cp /usr/local/lib/rstudio-server/extras/launchd/com.rstudio.launchd.rserver.plist /Library/LaunchDaemon
```

**NOTE:** You can start the service using `lanunchctl` but I couldn't find the proper way to do it. A workaround is to restart your system.

- Set minimum user id accepted by RStudio

If you cannot log in with your user, it might be that it has a user id < 1000 (like in my case- to check the user id type `id` in a shell and check the value of `uid` at the beginning of the output). Then you need to create a directory called *rstudio* in /etc

```
cd /etc
mkdir rstudio
cd rstudio
```

Then create file named *rserver.conf* and add the following line, changing `100` by some value >100 and <=your user-id

```
auth-minimum-user-id=101
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer; could you please tell me if you have this file `/opt/rstudio-tools/boost/boost_1_50_0/lib/libboost_date_time.a`?

Comment: Yes. Don't you? Do you see any error when you run `install-dependencies-osx`? That's the step that installs boost in /opt (I see many warnings myself, but not errors so I assume it installs OK).

Comment: That's the weird part. I do not have it even though `install-dependencies-osx` does install the respective deps, including `boost`. However, that specific file does not get installed... I am trying a different route now which is to install rstudio-server which is via `brew install rstudio-server`.

Comment: I see. Are you using Apple's compiler or is there any chance it is compiling with some other compiler? Good luck with the brew attempt!

Comment: @ddiez: I could successfully install rstudio server on osx (there is some problem on CMakeList.txt file when downloaded from rstudio server website but your git link version worked perfectly!) but when I type rstudio-server verify-installation, it says rstudio-server: command not found even after I restarted. Any clue?